# global.location not working in Jest tests

Tags: reactjs, jsdom, jestjs

I have an app that's built with Webpack that is tested with Jest. Recently I updated Jest to version 0.8.0 and Node to version 5.

I have tests for several components that read from `global.location`. Previously, I would set global.location myself like this:

```
global.location = {
  hash: '#hash'
};
```

This worked fine until the upgrade; now none of the components using global work and when I print global.location I get:

```
Location {}
```

It seems like there is now some external library attempting to mock the window's location object... any ideas how to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out while I was writing out the question :^P

It seems like the issue was that `jsdom`, which is used by Jest, is in more recent versions trying to mock the location object. The source code indicates that the implementation is still a bit half-baked, but I was able to work around my particular problem with:

```
global.location.replace('#hash');
```